# Publishing community with sfdx force:community:publish - Error: 'The requested resource does not exist'

Tags: community, salesforcedx, deployment, error, experience-cloud

My team and I are setting up our build pipeline, such that after we deploy our community to an environment, we follow up with running the publish command, to ensure all changes go live. We run this from a script, using Travis as our CI provider.

The command we run is:
`sfdx force:community:publish --targetusername "$USERNAME" --name "$COMMUNITY_NAME"`

This fails the build, with an error of
`'The requested resource does not exist'`

Despite the failure, the community still executes the publish, i.e. its not an issue with not being able to locate the community.

I don't get any issues when running it from my local to my default scratch org. Our initial thoughts were that perhaps the user running the command doesn't have the required permissions, but they seem to be set up fine. A short-term fix would be to ignore this error, and making it nonblocking, since the publish does indeed occur, but this is not particularly clean.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Could this perhaps be a race condition? If you have the CI job sleep for say a minute or two between the metadata deployment and the community publish, does it go away? (I've seen a number of race conditions in Communities CICD).

Comment: @DavidReed - Thanks for getting back to me, I had thought the same, but I've tested the publish in isolation as well, i.e. by running the publish by itself (no deploy), and I still get the same error

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing and found that when I'm executing the publish command, the site is there but in an odd state. When I examine the sfdx.log I see that sfdx can find the site by name in the Network table, but when it POSTs to the URL to publish (https://hostname.cs2.my.salesforce.com/connect/communities/0DBXXXXXXXXXXXX/publish), the URL returns a 404